# ggplot2 axis labelling when overriding aesthetics in a geom

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, axis

When I override `x` or `y` in a `geom` function, the axis labels are wrong.

Sample data, offsets included so we can tell what we are plotting, and a plot of A against B:

```
d=data.frame(A=runif(10),B=100+runif(10),C=200+runif(10))
g = ggplot(d,aes(A,B))
g + geom_point()
```

Everything there looks okay, but:

```
g + geom_point(aes(B,C))
```

plots the values of B against C but the axis labels are A and B still. Do I have to explicitly label thus:

```
g+geom_point(aes(B,C))+xlab("B") + ylab("C")
```

every time I do this? Is overriding aesthetics this way a Bad Thing and I should really create a new `g` object?

Comment: Could you explain in which situation this is needed? Or a minimal example? I.e. why don't you simple do `g = ggplot(d,aes(B,C)) + geom_point()`

Comment: If you expect to do something like that, it would seem best not to specify the aes in `ggplot`, e.g. `g = ggplot(d); g + geom_point(aes(A,B)); g + geom_point(aes(B,C))`.

Comment: If I've got a `g` lying around I thought I could re-use it. Is the replacement of aesthetics only meant for adding further geoms to a plot? `g+geom_point() + geom_point(aes(y=Z2))+geom_point(y=Z3)` ?

Comment: I think the point is that aesthetics defined in the `ggplot` call are fundamental to the plot. It's not so much that replacing aesthetics is a Bad Thing, but that any aesthetics defined in the `ggplot` call ought to have some relevance to the plot (thus the default axis labeling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default labels for an axis comes from the name of the variable that was first mapped to the aesthetic. In your case, in the original `ggplot` call (stored in `g`), you map `x` to `A`. Even if no geom uses that particular mapping, it is the first mapping and thus sets the (default) label of the axis. As you noted, you can override that default with `xlab`, etc.